# Unix Script Exit Status History

Tags: unix

There is a existing script which run daily. Is it possible to track return code of scripts after its completion to track that it was successfully finished or not in its previous run? I don't want to modify the existing script.

Comment: What kind of script are you talking about? Could you post the contents here? Can you write try catch in that script language?

Answer (score 0):

After the script was executed, its exit code is stored in the `$?` variable, which you could save to a file. For example

```
/path/to/script.sh
echo $? >> /path/to/script.log
```

You probably want to save the date too:

```
/path/to/script.sh
result=$?
echo $(date) $result >> /path/to/script.log
```